# Problema de Javascript

Tags: javascript

Quiero construir una tabla en javascript utilizando dos arrays uno para los meses y otro para los dias de cada mes. Quiero mostrar una fila con los meses y debajo una fila con los dias. Empeze de la siguiente forma:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
  var meses =["enero","febrero","marzo","abril","mayo","junio","julio","agosto","septiembre","octubre","noviembre","diciembre"];
  var dias = [31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31];

  var result = "";

  for (var i = 0; i < meses.length; i++) {
   document.write(meses[i]+" ");
   for (var j = 0; j < dias.length; j++) {
    document.write(dias[j]);
   }
  }

  //document.getElementById("meses").innerHTML = "<td>"+meses[i]+"</td>";
  //document.getElementById("dias").innerHTML = "<td>"+dias[j]+"</td>";

 </script>
```

Pero no me funciona... no se como hacer que los dos arrays se unan para poder insertarlos en una tabla...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te Falta iniciar la tabla, las filas y las columnas, además tus ciclos no deben ir anidados, de lo contrario mostrarías todos los dias por cada mes, sabiendo esto tu código debe quedar así:

```
var meses =["enero","febrero","marzo","abril","mayo","junio","julio","agosto","septiembre","octubre","noviembre","diciembre"];
var dias = [31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31];
var result = "";
document.write("<table><tr>")
for ( i = 0; i < 12; i++)
{
    document.write("<td>"+meses[i]+" </td>");
}
document.write("</tr><tr>")
for ( j = 0; j < 12; j++) {
    document.write("<td>"+dias[j]+" </td>");
}
document.write("</tr></table>")
```